# Dompdf Laravel Test

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am having problems resolving this issue. I want the user to be able to download a report when pressing the button. I keep on getting Action not defined, and if I change my route it will simply not load the app.

Any help would be appreciated.

/************View***************/

```
<a href="{{URL::action('ReportController@pdf',[$report->Report_ID])}}"><button>Download PDF</button></a>
```

/*************Controller****************/

```
 public function pdf($id){
   $report=Report::findorFail($id);
   $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.show', compact('report'));
   return $pdf->download('server_report.pdf');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your action defined in a route.

For example:

`Route::get('pdf','ReportController@pdf');`

Also, make sure that if ReportController has a resource route then the pdf route goes above it.